# How to choose thirdy party package versions with upgrading Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

For reach release of Laravel the advice is to upgrade the 3rd party packages.  For example, this is from the release notes for Laravel 6:

> Next, examine any 3rd party packages consumed by your application and
> verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 6 support.

How do I know which is the "proper version for Laravel 6 support"?

When I check the Packagist entries for components listed in `composer.json` it usually states which PHP versions it is compatible with, and lists its own dependencies, but there is rarely (if ever) any mention of compatible Laravel versions.

Comment: packages will usually have dependencies on the laravel framework's sub packages, like `illuminate\support` or the likes, and they will have version constraints on them

Comment: Look at their `composer.json` it will certainly have requirements for Laravel if it needs them. If it doesn't, then it's not a Laravel-specific package and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, all packages contains their required versions in their own `composer.json`. By using `composer why-not laravel/framework 6.0.0`, you can check which packages are not yet compatible **before** running `composer update`